# Java JNI: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION: Failed to write core dump

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, native

I am attempting to write a native method for use in java, for speed purposes, and it doesn't work. It compiles ok, but sometimes it does absolutely nothing, sometimes it says this:

```
`Execution protection violation
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00009f0a, pid=8768,  tid=8780
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_05-b13) (build 1.8.0_05- b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.5-b02 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00009f0a
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client  versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Nate\Documents\Programming\eclipse\APCS\Bits\hs_err_pid8768.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
# http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#`
```

Here's the native method declaration:
`public static native byte[][][] createArray();`

And here's the .cpp file:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "NativeTest.h"

JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL 
    Java_NativeTest_createArray(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls){
        printf("Native method running");
        jobjectArray joa;
        jbyteArray jba;
        jclass joaCls = env->GetObjectClass(joa);
        jclass jbaCls = env->GetObjectClass(jba); 
        return (*env).NewObjectArray(20, joaCls, (*env).NewObjectArray(20, jbaCls, (*env).NewByteArray(3)));
}

int main(){
}
```

If you'd like to see anything else, I can post it. Error log gives nothing useful to me but maybe someone else can decipher it.
I've heard that these errors are usually due to illegal array / memory accessing; can you not initialize jarrays like that?

Comment: `jobjectArray` and `jbyteArray` are just pointers under the hood. You are not initializing them, so your `GetObjectClass()` calls are essentially praying that they have access to whatever address the uninitialized pointers point to.

Comment: @zenzelezz In that case, how do I get the jclass in order to create the arrays? I tried Findclass - how I thought it was supposed to work, anyway - and got the same error.

Comment: I'm not sure how to accomplish a three-dimensional array like you're trying to, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6155813/74739) might point you in the right direction.