# Return multidimensional array in JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, android-studio, java-native-interface

I want to return an already existing multidimensional array from C++ to Java code. My code is as below:

```
int cells [3][3] = {{0}};

int[][]
Java_com_packagename_appname_GameView_addNew(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject, int row, int col, int val) {
    cells[row][col] = val;
    return cells;
}
```

But obviously it's not working. What would be the proper way?

Comment: Perhaps check the more general question of [return 2d primitive array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143134/return-a-2d-primitive-array-from-c-to-java-from-jni-ndk)

Comment: That answer is confusing. I think it shouldn't be that complicated and lengthy.

Comment: But did you try it? Like it or not, JNI tends to be verbose, and all things considered that code isn't that big.

Comment: @zenzelezz, I didn't try it because I don't understand where to put the `cells` array in that code.

Comment: @Nafis When you passed your Java code through `javah` to get the prototype for your native C code, what did you get?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I couldn't pass the code to java, there were errors. Like "unexpected symbol" for int[][] etc.

Comment: @Nafis You have to pass your Java code through `javah` to get native function prototypes. Once you get the function prototypes, you then use those prototypes *exactly as they are* to create your calls.  There is no way for native code to return `int[][]` - it will return a `jobjectArray`.  A multidimensional array in Java is an array of arrays - and an array in Java is an object.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I am using Android Studio with gradle. So, I believe the `javah` part is taken care of in background. Now that you mentioned about  `jobjectArray` it's making more sense now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return a 2D primitive array from C to Java from JNI/NDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143134/return-a-2d-primitive-array-from-c-to-java-from-jni-ndk)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int cells [3][3] = {{0}};

jobjectArray
Java_com_packagename_appname_GameView_addNew(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject, int row, int col, int val) {

    cells[row][col] = val;

    // Get the int array class
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("[I");

    jintArray iniVal = env->NewIntArray(3);
    // Create the returnable jobjectArray with an initial value
    jobjectArray outer = env->NewObjectArray(3,cls, iniVal);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        jintArray inner = env->NewIntArray(3);
        env->SetIntArrayRegion(inner, 0, 3, cells[i]);
        // set inner's values
        env->SetObjectArrayElement(outer, i, inner);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(inner);
    }
    return outer;
}
```

Comment: By doing the exact same thing I am getting ```JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: attempt to return an instance of int[][] from java.lang.Integer[][]```. Any idea?

Comment: Renauld, In the FindClass call "[I" - this implies an array of int. If it were "[java/lang/Integer" then it would have a different type which may solve this error.

Comment: Beautiful. Worked right out of the box.